# React Native: Call Redux getState() inside Component

Tags: react-native, redux

What I'm trying to achieve is this: I want to check whether the NavigationDrawer is open and if yes, then when the user clicks back (on Android) I want to close the drawer instead of quitting the app. I have a boolean (isDrawerOpen) in the Redux stored which is updated properly.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to call `getState()` inside my component. The component looks something like this:

```
class MainScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function () {
      if (somehow.getState().isDrawerOpen) {
        // Close drawer.
        return true;
      } 

      return false;
    });
  }

  render() {
      return ...
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    ...
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainScreen)
```

And the store is created in another container component, like this:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                 <MainScreen />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

In my `MainScreen` component whenever I need to dispatch an action, I do it by calling `this.props.dispatch(someAction())`. However, `this.props.getState()` doesn't seem to exist.

One solution of course would be to update my MainScreen's state whenever the mapStateToProps() is triggered and then instead of checking Redux's state, check the component's state. However, updating my component's state would cause the render() to be triggered and that's not what I want. Besides, I would like to anyhow know for future reference how to access Redux's state from inside a component.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You get redux's "state" by using mapStateToProps and using the props inside your component. In most cases with redux, you will not use `this.state` inside your components, instead you will be using the `this.props` which initially comes from your mapStateToProps. In your case I would store the drawers open/close state on the redux state itself, then have a redux action to open/close it (change the bool or whatever). Then you would map it into your component, something like `this.props. isDrawerOpen`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I do store the drawer's state in Redux and I do have a specific action for this. Also, whenever the drawer's state changes, the mapStateToProps is triggered with the correct info. So far so good. The problem then is that the MainScreen cannot update its own props so I would have to map the state I received from Redux to the MainScreen's state by calling `setState`. However, this would trigger MainScreen's `render()` again and that's not what I want.

Comment: You should avoid using setState if you can, I would just use a redux action, or an init state of some kind? There are trick with avoiding render by checking `shouldComponentUpdate`'s props. For example, reacts mixin PureRenderMixin does just this to try an avoid rendering if props have not changed.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Overriding the `shouldComponentUpdate` was a good hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put the `BackAndroid.addEventListener` inside the constructor because the props there don't change. You need to put the listener in either `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` in order to be *able to* check the latest state of your `props`. Then inside your listener, check for `this.props.isDrawerOpen`, which should be automatically passed and updated from the top by your `connect`'s `mapStateToProps`. You should never have to call `getState` inside a `connect`ed component.

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying. Could you help me understand a bit more what you mean? I don't see how the `MainScreen` can update its own props. First, the `mapStateToProps` will be called and there I can map Redux's state to some new props. Then the `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` inside the MainScreen will be triggered with these new props. Finally, since the MainScreen can't update its own props, I would instead have to map these props to the MainScreen's state by calling `setState`. But this would trigger again the render() and I don't want this to happen. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show me how you connected your drawer to redux?

Comment: I use react-native-drawer and I put it in a different component than the MainScreen. The MainScreen is actually the drawer's child. In the drawer's onOpen/onClose I call `this.props.dispatch(updateDrawerState(true))` passing true/false respectively. The `mapStateToProps` that is connected to the MainScreen has the correct Redux state always. So that works as expected.

Comment: Can you update your code above to show how you have the main screen as a child of the drawer but most importantly how it is connected to redux.

Comment: @Giorgos, you're not supposed to call `getState` inside a `connect`ed component, that's `mapStateToProps`'s job to do that, to get specific data from the store and pass it down to the component. When you dispatch an action, the action goes through the reducer, updates the state, and the updated values are passed down to every `connect`ed component as `props`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I think the correct answer is what you said "You're not supposed to call `getState()` inside a connected component".